# $M_1\otimes N$ is not submodule of $M\otimes N$ where $M_1$ is submodule of $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to know the example : $M_1\otimes N$ is not submodule of $M\otimes N$ where $M_1$ is submodule of $M$ and these are $R$-modules.

In the book, if $M_1\oplus M'\neq M$ then this is possible.

For instance if $R={\mathbb Z}$, since ${\mathbb Z}_m\otimes {\mathbb Z}_n = {\mathbb Z}_{(m,n)}$, so there is no counterexample.

What is an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know if this is what you want but $2\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_2\cong \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_2\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. However the map $ i:2\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ induced by inclusion is the zero map.